# Laravel 5.1 session not saving

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

My session driver is memcached.

When I fire an event and broadcast event in redis, the flash messages are not saving, but If I don't fire an event it works just fine.

I'm on Laravel 5.1.

Please help me.

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
SESSION_DRIVER=memcached
```

my code look like this

```
 if ($isEmployee)
    {
        event(new AccountUpdated($data));
    }


  Session::flash('notification', 'Account has been updated.');

  return redirect()->back();
```

I'm using socket.io for the event and works fine

but the flash message are not saving.

If I don't fire the event the flash message are working fine.

Comment: Please include your configuration for sessions / cache etc. in the question

Comment: thanks David. Why do you think it's not saving when I'm firing event?

Comment: We need real code to be able to solve the problem.

Comment: he event is broadcasted correctly and the view updates in real time. My problem is that when I fire the event my flash messages are not saved but only when I fire the event.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't used socket.io and my guess is data stored in the session using `flash`  method will only be available during the subsequent HTTP request, and then will be deleted. so when you broad cast which is a request(i believe) then the flash variable gets deleted and in next redirect.
try `with` method for any luck

```
return Redirect::to('user/login')->with('message', 'Login Failed');
```

If you need to keep your flash data around for even more requests, you may use the reflash method, which will keep all of the flash data around for an additional request. If you only need to keep specific flash data around, you may use the keep method:

```
$request->session()->reflash();
```

reference:http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#flash-data